# sql Insert multiple arrays and count them

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I am getting arrays from post for to insert database. I am getting names from days tab in the form. I am making a loop for inserting but **couldn't get the total count for it**. Some of days are null, some are different totals.

Tried to add hidden input for them but couldn't get success. I think maybe I can count total arrays and make it loop limit.

I am inserting array to `sql` with this code but it insert only one. counting from `mon` is wrong, I know, but I don't know how can I get total loop limit for all arrays:

```
$i = 0;
foreach($_POST['mon'] as $item){
    $mon= DB::control($_POST['mon'][$i],'text');
    $tue= DB::control($_POST['tue'][$i],'text');
    $wed= DB::control($_POST['wed'][$i],'text');
    $thu= DB::control($_POST['thu'][$i],'text');
    $fri= DB::control($_POST['fri'][$i],'text');
    $sat= DB::control($_POST['sat'][$i],'text');
    $sun= DB::control($_POST['sun'][$i],'text');
    $query = DB::insert("INSERT INTO work(mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat,sun) VALUES($mon,$tue,$wed,$thu,$fri,$sat,$sun)");
    $i++;
}
```

**Edit :** Tried for counting arrays, i could count full arrays but counted null array too.

```
$d1 = count($_POST['mon']);
$d2 = count($_POST['tue']);
$d3 = count($_POST['wed']);     
$d4 = count($_POST['thu']);
$d5 = count($_POST['fri']);
$d6 = count($_POST['sat']);
$d7 = count($_POST['sun']);

$total = $d1+$d2+$d3+$d4+$d5+$d6+$d7;
```

**Edit Var_dump :**

```
array(10) { ["city"]=> string(7) "Abcdef" ["que"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(6) "que[]" } ["mon"]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "2" [2]=> string(1) "3" } ["tue"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "2" } ["wed"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } ["thur"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } ["fri"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } ["sat"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } ["sun"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(6) "trial" } ["psd"]=> string(19) "psdAddReport" }
```

**Update :**
Thanks a lot. I could count arrays with your way but I thought wrong way for my solution. I added  while code for loop to insert. For ex. counted 4 and inserted it for 4 times. This is my fault.

TABS in the `html` form

```
Tab_City | Mon | Tue | Wed | Thur | Fri | Sat | Sun 
-----------------------------------------------------
 abc     | a   |  a  |  a  | aaa  | aa  |     |  aaa
         | a   |  a  |  a  | aaa  | aa  |     |  aaa
         | a   |  a  |     | aaa  | aa  |     |  aaa
         | a   |  a  |     | aaa  | aa  |     |  aaa
         | a   |  a  |     | aaa  | aa  |     |  aaa 
         | a   |     |     | aaa  | aa  |     |  aaa
         | a   |     |     |      | aa  |     |  aaa
         | a   |     |     |      | aa  |     |  aaa
         | a   |     |     |      | aa  |     | 
         | a   |     |     |      |     |     |
```

There are 50 arrays but 10 rows. I counted 50 arrays but now I am thinking getting the biggest days count will work for me. Please say if I am wrong or any easy way. I want to learn coding.
Thanks.

**SQL**

```
id   |city | mon | tue | wed | thur | fri | sat | sun
-----|-----|-----|-----|------|-----|-----|------------
 1   |abc  | a   |  a  |  a  | aaa  | aa  |     |  aaa
 2   |abc  | a   |  a  |  a  | aaa  | aa  |     |  aaa
 3   |abc  | a   |  a  |     | aaa  | aa  |     |  aaa
 4   |abc  | a   |  a  |     | aaa  | aa  |     |  aaa
 5   |abc  | a   |  a  |     | aaa  | aa  |     |  aaa 
 6   |abc  | a   |     |     | aaa  | aa  |     |  aaa
 7   |abc  | a   |     |     |      | aa  |     |  aaa
 8   |abc  | a   |     |     |      | aa  |     |  aaa
 9   |abc  | a   |     |     |      | aa  |     | 
10   |abc  | a   |     |     |      |     |     |
```

Comment: If you don't use the `$item` in the loop - why not simple `for` loop? what exactly you want to count? can you please add simple example of input and desire output?

Comment: I am trying to add values came from days from form. Trying different things from web, $item stayed from one of them. 
Form Tabs are days. In every days tab i am entering worker names. I want to make a form for a week.

$d1 = count($_POST['mon']);
$d2 = count($_POST['tue']);
$d3 = count($_POST['wed']);  
$d4 = count($_POST['thu']);
$d5 = count($_POST['fri']);
$d6 = count($_POST['sat']);
$d7 = count($_POST['sun']);

$total = $d1+$d2+$d3+$d4+$d5+$d6+$d7;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with `array_sum(array_map('count', $arr))`. Array map will execute `count` function on each element and then the `array_sum` will sum them all. Use `array_filter` to **filter out null and empty array**.

Consider the following example:

```
$arr["mon"] = ["a", "b", "c"];
$arr["tue"] = null;
$arr["wed"] = [];
$arr["thu"] = ["1", "2"];

$total = array_sum(array_map('count', array_filter($arr)));

echo $total; // print 5
```

Reference: [array_sum](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php), [array_map](https://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php), [array_filter](https://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

**Edit:**

```
$_POST["mon"] = ["a", "b", "c"];
$_POST["bbb"] = null;
$_POST["city"] = "aaaaaa";
$_POST["psd"] = "psdAddReport";
$_POST["wed"] = [""];
$_POST["eee"] = ["55", 232];
$_POST["tue"] = ["1", "2"];

$days = ["mon", "wed", "tue"]; // can add here all days
foreach($_POST as $k => $v)
    if (in_array($k, $days))
        $arr[] = $v;
// now $arr contains only days element

$total = array_sum(array_map('count', array_map('array_filter',array_filter($arr))));
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. I think this will solve my question. How can i apply this for my codes. For example is it true  ? $arr["mon"] = DB::control($_POST['mon'][$i],'text'); And my for each loop is wrong as you said. Thanks and regards again.